# How to add hours in a TO_TIMESTAMP function?

Tags: sql, dremio

New to SQL

I am using the `TO_TIMESTAMP` feature to change a column to datetime. Is there anyway I can apply a subtraction of 5 hours into the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function that would apply it everytime the SQL is ran?

How I am using it currently:

```
select col1
TO_TIMESTAMP(col2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"' ) as col2 from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
SELECT 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(col2,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"' ) - INTERVAL '5' HOUR td
FROM Table1
```